# How to find row of matching column values in a sheet containing a database

Tags: excel, vba

I want to match a series of column values in a sheet containing a database.

I would like to get the values for the columns H, I, Y and Z on the central database (ws_data), for the corresponding A, B, C, D values that must match the initial input data on the ws_3 sheet. I believe I can do this by finding which row matches the values from the input.

For each row that must be matched, I loop through all the rows on the database to find the row that matches the desired values. I keep getting no output. I tried to set a limit for the max number of rows on the database.

```vb
Sub match_values()

Dim ws_data As Worksheet, ws_3 As Worksheet
Set ws_data = Sheets("Database2") ' Sheet containing my database
Set ws_3 = Sheets("Folha4") 'sheet where i need the values matched from my database
Dim rng2 As Range

'Setting the number of rows to be matched
Set rng2 = ws_3.Range("B10:B" & ws_3.Range("B10").End(xlDown).Row)

For Each n In rng2.Rows

    i = n.Row
    q = 8
    max_q = ws_data.Range("A8").End(xlDown).Row

    Do Until _
      ws_3.Cells(i, "H").Value = ws_data.Cells(q, "A").Value And _
      ws_3.Cells(i, "C").Value = ws_data.Cells(q, "B").Value And _
      ws_3.Cells(i, "D").Value = ws_data.Cells(q, "C").Value And _
      ws_3.Cells(i, "F").Value = ws_data.Cells(q, "D").Value Or _
      q = max_q + 8
        
        If ws_3.Cells(i, "H").Value = ws_data.Cells(q, "A").Value And _
          ws_3.Cells(i, "C").Value = ws_data.Cells(q, "B").Value And _
          ws_3.Cells(i, "D").Value = ws_data.Cells(q, "C").Value And _
          ws_3.Cells(i, "F").Value = ws_data.Cells(q, "D").Value Then: MsgBox q 'get the row that matches the values to look up
        
        q = q + 1
        
        On Error Resume Next
    Loop
Next
End Sub
```

Input sheet:

| Pos. | Rails | Zone | Panel # | Sheet. Type | Sheet. Pos | Series | Bf (m) | Uf (W/(m².°C)) | ψ (W/(m.°C) | fRsi |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3R | SUP | 1 | SLD | P1 | 38 |  |  |  |  |
| 2 | 3R | SUP | 2 | SLD | P2 | 38 |  |  |  |  |
| 3 | 3R | INF | 1 | SLD | P1 | 38 |  |  |  |  |
| 4 | 3R | INF | 2 | SLD | P2 | 38 |  |  |  |  |
| 5 | 3R | LAT | 1 | SLD | P1 | 38 |  |  |  |  |
| 6 | 2R | CC | 1_2 | - | - | 38 |  |  |  |  |
| 7 | 3R | LAT | 2 | SLD | P2 | 38 |  |  |  |  |

[image: Input sheet]

Database:

| Series | Rails | Zone | Type | Sheet Pos. | Bf [mm] | Uf | ψ_ | frsi_ |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 38 | 1R | INF | FIX | P1 | 58.50 | 2.257 | 0.0425 | 0.7068 |  |  |
| 38 | 1R | INF | SLD | P1 | 58.51 | 3.785 | 0.0513 | 0.5485 |  |  |
| 38 | 1R | LAT | FIX | P1 | 53.02 | 2.199 | 0.0405 | 0.7068 |  |  |
| 38 | 1R | LAT | SLD | P1 | 74.76 | 5.325 | 0.0370 | 0.5468 |  |  |
| 38 | 1R | SUP | FIX | P1 | 53.02 | 2.199 | 0.0405 | 0.7068 |  |  |
| 38 | 1R | SUP | SLD | P1 | 56.51 | 3.977 | 0.0450 | 0.5318 |  |  |
| 38 | 2R | CC | 20IN |  | 20.13 | 19.754 | 0.0663 | 0.1785 |  |  |
| 38 | 2R | CC | 20N |  | 20.13 | 15.782 | 0.0650 | 0.1578 |  |  |
| 38 | 2R | INF | FIX | P1 | 58.48 | 2.1727 | 0.0425 | 0.7128 |  |  |
| 38 | 2R | INF | FIX | P2 | 58.48 | 2.24 | 0.0385 | 0.6943 |  |  |
| 38 | 2R | INF | PIV | P2 | 96.87 | 3.177 | 0.0389 | #VALOR! |  |  |
| 38 | 2R | INF | SLD | P1 | 58.48 | 3.53 | 0.0428 | 0.5768 |  |  |
| 38 | 2R | INF | SLD | P2 | 58.48 | 3.729 | 0.0400 | 0.5620 |  |  |
| 38 | 2R | LAT | FIX | P1 | 53.03 | 2.12 | 0.0409 | #VALOR! |  |  |
| 38 | 2R | LAT | FIX | P2 | 53.02 | 2.175 | 0.0389 | #VALOR! |  |  |
| 38 | 2R | LAT | PIV | P2 | 102.46 | 2.742 | 0.0399 | #VALOR! |  |  |
| 38 | 2R | LAT | SLD | P1 | 74.78 | 5.109 | 0.0339 | #VALOR! |  |  |
| 38 | 2R | LAT | SLD | P2 | 74.78 | 5.228 | 0.0369 | #VALOR! |  |  |
| 38 | 2R | SUP | FIX | P1 | 56.48 | 2.263 | 0.0419 | #VALOR! |  |  |
| 38 | 2R | SUP | FIX | P2 | 56.48 | 2.431 | 0.0409 | #VALOR! |  |  |
| 38 | 2R | SUP | PIV | P1 | 96.87 | 3.218 | 0.0389 | #VALOR! |  |  |
| 38 | 2R | SUP | PIV | P2 | 96.87 | 3.179 | 0.0389 | #VALOR! |  |  |
| 38 | 2R | SUP | SLD | P1 | 56.48 | 3.841 | 0.0459 | #VALOR! |  |  |
| 38 | 2R | SUP | SLD | P2 | 56.48 | 4.103 | 0.0419 | #VALOR! |  |  |
| 38 | 3R | INF | FIX | P2 | 58.49 | 2.152 | 0.0385 | 0.6993 |  |  |
| 38 | 3R | INF | SLD | P1 | 58.48 | 3.555 | 0.0500 | 0.5728 |  |  |
| 38 | 3R | INF | SLD | P2 | 58.48 | 3.662 | 0.0460 | 0.5885 |  |  |
| 38 | 3R | INF | SLD | P3 |  |  | #VALOR! | #VALOR! |  |  |
| 38 | 3R | LAT | FIX | P1 | 53.02 | 2.122 | 0.0393 | 0.7150 |  |  |
| 38 | 3R | LAT | FIX | P2 | 52.97 | 2.109 | 0.0368 | 0.7023 |  |  |
| 38 | 3R | LAT | FIX | P3 | 53.02 | 2.199 | 0.0368 | 0.6983 |  |  |
| 38 | 3R | LAT | SLD | P1 |  |  | #VALOR! | #VALOR! |  |  |
| 38 | 3R | LAT | SLD | P2 | 74.74 | 5.279 | 0.0373 | 0.5698 |  |  |
| 38 | 3R | LAT | SLD | P3 |  |  | #VALOR! | #VALOR! |  |  |
| 38 | 3R | SUP | FIX | P1 | 56.48 | 2.157 | 0.0403 | 0.7150 |  |  |
| 38 | 3R | SUP | FIX | P2 | 56.48 | 2.142 | 0.0378 | 0.7000 |  |  |
| 38 | 3R | SUP | FIX | P3 | 56.48 | 2.23 | 0.0378 | 0.6943 |  |  |
| 38 | 3R | SUP | SLD | P1 | 56.48 | 3.802 | 0.0440 | 0.5508 |  |  |
| 38 | 3R | SUP | SLD | P2 | 56.49 | 4.027 | 0.0403 | 0.5535 |  |  |
| 38 | 3R | SUP | SLD | P3 | 56.48 | 4.105 | 0.0410 | 0.5510 |  |  |

[image: Database]

Comment: Please copy your input and output data as tables, instead of as an image; it's easier for answerers to copy/paste them into Excel. You can do this by copying the data in Excel; go to [Markdown table generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables), choose **File** -> **Paste table data...**; then click **Generate** and **Copy to clipboard**. Then you can edit your question and paste the table into it.

Comment: Also, you should consider adding `Option Explicit` at the top of your code file (if it's not already there); there's an option in the VBA IDE to add this in for every new module you create from now on. `Option Explicit` forces you to declare your variables -- e.g. `Dim ws_data As Worksheet` -- so you don't have to worry about introducing new variables by misspelling them.

Comment: If I understand correctly, I think you might be able to use MATCH and avoid VBA altogether. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My first instinct is to suggest an SQL statement to join the two ranges:

```sql
SELECT Folha.*, Data.*
FROM [Folha!B9:Q16] AS Folha
INNER JOIN [Database2$] AS Data
    ON Folha.Series = Data.Series
    AND Folha.Rails = Data.Rails
    AND Folha.Zone = Data.Zone
    AND Folha.[Sheet. Type] = Data.Type
```

Assuming the rows in `Database2` are unique (and if not, you can modify the SQL statement to account for that), you will get back the data from `Folha` matched with the data from `Database2` on those columns.

In order to execute an SQL statement against Excel data, I usually use ADO. Add a reference (**Tools** -> **References...**) to **Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects**; choose the latest version, which is usually **6.1**.

Then, you can write code like the following:

```vba
Const filename = "C:\path\to\excel\file.xlsx"

Dim connectionString As String
connectionString = _
    "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
    "Data Source=""" & filepath & """;" & _
    "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes"""
    
    ' If your data is in a macro-enabled file (.xlsm), the previous line should
    ' look like this:
    ' "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Macro;HDR=No"""
    
Dim sql As String
sql = _
    "SELECT Folha.*, Data.* " & _
    "FROM [Folha!B9:Q16] AS Folha " & _
    "INNER JOIN [Database2$] AS Data " & _
        "ON Folha.Series = Data.Series " & _
        "AND Folha.Rails = Data.Rails " & _
        "AND Folha.Zone = Data.Zone " & _
        "AND Folha.[Sheet. Type] = Data.Type"

Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
rs.Open sql, connectionString
```

Currently, each row in the recordset has data from `Folha` followed by the matched data in `Database2`. You may want to shape the SQL statement to return only the desired data.

You haven't indicated what you'd like to do with the returned data. But one thing you can do: you could paste the data in the recordset directly to an Excel worksheet using the **CopyFromRecordset** method. The following pastes the results into a new worksheet:

```vb
Worksheets.Add.Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset(rs)
```

**References:**

Microsoft Access SQL (used when querying Excel files):

- [Basic concepts, vocabulary, and syntax](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/access-sql-basic-concepts-vocabulary-and-syntax-444d0303-cde1-424e-9a74-e8dc3e460671#:%7E:text=Relational%20database%20programs%2C%20such%20as,such%20as%20ISO%20and%20ANSI.)
- [Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/microsoft-access-sql-reference)

ADODB:

- [**Recordset** object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/recordset-object-ado)

  - [**Open** method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/open-method-ado-connection)

Excel:

- [**Range** object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range(object)) — [**CopyFromRecordset** method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.copyfromrecordset)

Comment: Thank you so much for all your inputs. Unfortunately, my coding skills are not that great.
I was very intrigued by this SQL approach, as I didn't know we could use this in excel. I will do some research to try to understand this. 
As you suggested, I've updated my original post with the tables. My goal, is to have a macro that could complete the Bf, Uf, ψ and frsi columns by matching the values on the database table. 
This might look like a silly question for someone that clearly dominates this, but is it possible to have this be done automatically no matter where the workbook is placed?

Comment: My goal is to have the database in the same workbook, to avoid have to reference any specific path as the document will be shared to multiple people. Additionally, I have some calculations being done on the database itself

Comment: @Gonçalo RE dynamic path -- It's not a silly question; you could use `ThisWorkbook.FullName` instead of the `filename` constant.